How can I avoid errors from Software Updates trying to update old kernel versions?
I receive the following error message from the Software Updates function in Open Suse Leap:
There is no update candidate for kernel-default-devel-5.14.21-150500.55.68.1.x86_64 

This happens if I try to apply all available updates, which always (probably since I updated to 15.5) include updates for kernel-devel and kernel-default-devel, both to version 5.14.21-150500.53.2. However YasT package management, under Multiversion packages, tells me that I only have 55.65 and 55.68 installed; these are also the only versions explicitly mentioned in my boot menu.
I have to manually exclude these two packages for the rest of the updates to succeed. What can I do to:

avoid these messages,
ensure that my updates work normally,
(avoid messing up my bootloader), and
if desirable, clean up any detritus from my system?

I forget why I installed these -devel packages, but I think it may have been because they provided files needed to build some software — or even out of simple curiosity.
Listings
(I am sorry about the German in some of these listings; I have several languages installed, and for some reason it often uses German instead of English!)
pjtraill@PatrickLaptopLinux:~> zypper search /^kernel/
S  | Name                                 | Summary                                                       | Type
---+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
   | kernel-64kb                          | Kernel with 64kb PAGE_SIZE                                    | Quellpaket
   | kernel-azure                         | Kernel for MS Azure cloud                                     | Paket
   | kernel-azure                         | Kernel for MS Azure cloud                                     | Quellpaket
   | kernel-azure-devel                   | Development files necessary for building kernel modules       | Paket
   | kernel-azure-extra                   | Kernel for MS Azure cloud - Unsupported kernel modules        | Paket
   | kernel-azure-livepatch-devel         | Kernel symbols file used during kGraft patch development      | Paket
   | kernel-azure-optional                | Kernel for MS Azure cloud - Optional kernel modules           | Paket
   | kernel-azure-vdso                    | vdso binaries for debugging purposes                          | Paket
   | kernel-debug                         | A Debug Version of the Kernel                                 | Paket
   | kernel-debug                         | A Debug Version of the Kernel                                 | Quellpaket
   | kernel-debug-devel                   | Development files necessary for building kernel modules       | Paket
   | kernel-debug-livepatch-devel         | Kernel symbols file used during kGraft patch development      | Paket
   | kernel-debug-vdso                    | vdso binaries for debugging purposes                          | Paket
i+ | kernel-default                       | The Standard Kernel                                           | Paket
   | kernel-default                       | The Standard Kernel                                           | Quellpaket
   | kernel-default-base                  | The Standard Kernel - base modules                            | Paket
   | kernel-default-base                  | The Standard Kernel - base modules                            | Quellpaket
   | kernel-default-base-rebuild          | Empty package to ensure rebuilding kernel-default-base in OBS | Paket
i+ | kernel-default-devel                 | Development files necessary for building kernel modules       | Paket
i+ | kernel-default-extra                 | The Standard Kernel - Unsupported kernel modules              | Paket
   | kernel-default-livepatch             | Metapackage to pull in matching kernel-livepatch package      | Paket
   | kernel-default-livepatch-devel       | Kernel symbols file used during kGraft patch development      | Paket
i+ | kernel-default-optional              | The Standard Kernel - Optional kernel modules                 | Paket
   | kernel-default-vdso                  | vdso binaries for debugging purposes                          | Paket
i+ | kernel-devel                         | Development files needed for building kernel modules          | Paket
   | kernel-devel-azure                   | Development files needed for building kernel modules          | Paket
   | kernel-devel-rt                      | Development files needed for building kernel modules          | Paket
   | kernel-docs                          | Kernel Documentation                                          | Paket
   | kernel-docs                          | Kernel Documentation                                          | Quellpaket
   | kernel-docs-html                     | Kernel Documentation (HTML)                                   | Paket
   | kernel-firmware                      | Linux kernel firmware files                                   | Paket
   | kernel-firmware                      | Linux kernel firmware files                                   | Quellpaket
i+ | kernel-firmware-all                  | Compatibility metapackage for kernel firmware files           | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-amdgpu               | Kernel firmware files for AMDGPU graphics driver              | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-ath10k               | Kernel firmware files for Atheros QCA988x WiFi drivers        | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-ath11k               | Kernel firmware files for Atheros Qualcomm WiFi drivers       | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-atheros              | Kernel firmware files for Atheros wireless drivers            | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-bluetooth            | Kernel firmware files for various Bluetooth drivers           | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-bnx2                 | Kernel firmware files for Broadcom network drivers            | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-brcm                 | Kernel firmware files for Broadcom wireless drivers           | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-chelsio              | Kernel firmware files for Chelsio network drivers             | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-dpaa2                | Kernel firmware files for NXP Management Complex bus driver   | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-i915                 | Kernel firmware files for Intel i915 graphics driver          | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-intel                | Kernel firmware files for Intel-platform device drivers       | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-iwlwifi              | Kernel firmware files for Intel wireless drivers              | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-liquidio             | Kernel firmware files for Cavium LiquidIO driver              | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-marvell              | Kernel firmware files for Marvell network drivers             | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-media                | Kernel firmware files for various Video4Linux drivers         | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-mediatek             | Kernel firmware files for Mediatek network drivers            | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-mellanox             | Kernel firmware files for Mellanox Spectrum switch driver     | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-mwifiex              | Kernel firmware files for Marvell WiFi fullmac drivers        | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-network              | Kernel firmware files for various network drivers             | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-nfp                  | Kernel firmware files for Netronome Flow Processor driver     | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-nvidia               | Kernel firmware files for Nvidia Tegra and graphics drivers   | Paket
   | kernel-firmware-nvidia-gsp-G06       | Kernel firmware file for open NVIDIA kernel module driver G06 | Paket
   | kernel-firmware-nvidia-gspx-G06      | Kernel firmware file for open NVIDIA kernel module driver G06 | Quellpaket
   | kernel-firmware-nvidia-gspx-G06      | Kernel firmware file for open NVIDIA kernel module driver G06 | Paket
   | kernel-firmware-nvidia-gspx-G06-cuda | Kernel firmware file for open NVIDIA kernel module driver G06 | Quellpaket
   | kernel-firmware-nvidia-gspx-G06-cuda | Kernel firmware file for open NVIDIA kernel module driver G06 | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-platform             | Kernel firmware files for various platform drivers            | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-prestera             | Kernel firmware files for Marvell Prestera ASIC driver        | Paket
i  | kernel-firmware-qcom                 | Kernel firmware files for Qualcomm device drivers             | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-qlogic               | Kernel firmware files for QLogic network drivers              | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-radeon               | Kernel firmware files for Radeon graphics driver              | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-realtek              | Kernel firmware files for Realtek wireless drivers            | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-serial               | Kernel firmware files for various serial drivers              | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-sound                | Kernel firmware files for various sound drivers               | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-ti                   | Kernel firmware files for Texas Instruments wireless drivers  | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-ueagle               | Kernel firmware files for Eagle IV USB ADSL modem driver      | Paket
i+ | kernel-firmware-usb-network          | Kernel firmware files for various USB WiFi / Ethernet drivers | Paket
i  | kernel-install-tools                 | Useful tools for installing self-built kernels                | Paket
   | kernel-kvmsmall                      | The Small Developer Kernel for KVM                            | Paket
   | kernel-kvmsmall                      | The Small Developer Kernel for KVM                            | Quellpaket
   | kernel-kvmsmall-devel                | Development files necessary for building kernel modules       | Paket
   | kernel-kvmsmall-livepatch-devel      | Kernel symbols file used during kGraft patch development      | Paket
   | kernel-kvmsmall-vdso                 | vdso binaries for debugging purposes                          | Paket
i+ | kernel-macros                        | RPM macros for building Kernel Module Packages                | Paket
   | kernel-obs-build                     | package kernel and initrd for OBS VM builds                   | Paket
   | kernel-obs-build                     | package kernel and initrd for OBS VM builds                   | Quellpaket
   | kernel-obs-qa                        | Basic QA tests for the kernel                                 | Paket
   | kernel-obs-qa                        | Basic QA tests for the kernel                                 | Quellpaket
   | kernel-rt                            | The Linux Kernel                                              | Paket
   | kernel-rt                            | The Linux Kernel                                              | Quellpaket
   | kernel-rt-devel                      | Development files necessary for building kernel modules       | Paket
   | kernel-rt-extra                      | The Linux Kernel - Unsupported kernel modules                 | Paket
   | kernel-rt-livepatch                  | Metapackage to pull in matching kernel-livepatch package      | Paket
   | kernel-rt-livepatch-devel            | Kernel symbols file used during kGraft patch development      | Paket
   | kernel-rt-optional                   | The Linux Kernel - Optional kernel modules                    | Paket
   | kernel-rt-vdso                       | vdso binaries for debugging purposes                          | Paket
   | kernel-rt_debug                      | The Linux Kernel                                              | Paket
   | kernel-rt_debug                      | The Linux Kernel                                              | Quellpaket
   | kernel-rt_debug-devel                | Development files necessary for building kernel modules       | Paket
   | kernel-rt_debug-livepatch-devel      | Kernel symbols file used during kGraft patch development      | Paket
   | kernel-rt_debug-vdso                 | vdso binaries for debugging purposes                          | Paket
i+ | kernel-source                        | The Linux Kernel Sources                                      | Paket
   | kernel-source                        | The Linux Kernel Sources                                      | Quellpaket
   | kernel-source-azure                  | The Linux Kernel Sources                                      | Paket
   | kernel-source-azure                  | The Linux Kernel Sources                                      | Quellpaket
   | kernel-source-rt                     | The Linux Kernel Sources                                      | Paket
   | kernel-source-rt                     | The Linux Kernel Sources                                      | Quellpaket
   | kernel-source-vanilla                | Vanilla Linux kernel sources with minor build fixes           | Paket
   | kernel-syms                          | Kernel Symbol Versions (modversions)                          | Paket
   | kernel-syms                          | Kernel Symbol Versions (modversions)                          | Quellpaket
   | kernel-syms-azure                    | Kernel Symbol Versions (modversions)                          | Paket
   | kernel-syms-azure                    | Kernel Symbol Versions (modversions)                          | Quellpaket
   | kernel-syms-rt                       | Kernel Symbol Versions (modversions)                          | Paket
   | kernel-syms-rt                       | Kernel Symbol Versions (modversions)                          | Quellpaket
   | kernel-vanilla                       | The Standard Kernel - without any SUSE patches                | Quellpaket
   | kernel-vanilla                       | The Standard Kernel - without any SUSE patches                | Paket
   | kernel-vanilla-base                  | The Standard Kernel - without any SUSE patches - base modules | Paket
   | kernel-vanilla-devel                 | Development files necessary for building kernel modules       | Paket
   | kernel-vanilla-livepatch-devel       | Kernel symbols file used during kGraft patch development      | Paket
   | kernel-zfcpdump                      | The IBM System Z zfcpdump Kernel                              | Quellpaket
   | kernelshark                          | GUI for trace-cmd                                             | Paket

zypper info kernel-devel:
Information for Paket kernel-devel:
-----------------------------------
Repository     : update-sle (15.5)
Name           : kernel-devel
Version        : 5.14.21-150500.55.68.1
Arch           : noarch
Anbieter       : SUSE LLC <https://www.suse.com/>
Installed Size : 59.1 MiB
Installed      : Yes
Status         : up-to-date
Quellpaket     : kernel-source-5.14.21-150500.55.68.1.src
Upstream-URL   : https://www.kernel.org/
Summary        : Development files needed for building kernel modules
Description    : 
    Kernel-level headers and Makefiles required for development of
    external kernel modules.


    Source Timestamp: 2024-06-05 21:39:05 +0000
    GIT Revision: 40e256a4a88f37d43c8f973ffe5bee78c5b1c679
    GIT Branch: SLE15-SP5


zypper repos
Repository-Prioritäten treten in Kraft:                                                                                                                                                                                                     (Siehe 'zypper lr -P' für Details)
      20 (erhöhte Priorität)  :  1 Repository
      99 (Standard-Priorität) : 12 Repositorys

#  | Alias                                | Name                                                         | Enabled | GPG Check | Refresh
---+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-----------+--------
 1 | NVIDIA:repo-non-free                 | repo-non-free (15.5)                                         | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes
 2 | download.nvidia.com-$releasever      | nVidia Graphics Drivers                                      | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes
 3 | http-download.opensuse.org-08194b20  | openSUSE:Leap:15.5:Update                                    | No      | ----      | ----
 4 | https-download.opensuse.org-1a3b4b18 | SUSE:SLE-15-SP2:GA                                           | No      | ----      | ----
 5 | https-download.opensuse.org-1df5925c | SUSE:SLE-15:GA                                               | No      | ----      | ----
 8 | https-download.opensuse.org-4e7c4183 | devel:languages:rust                                         | No      | ----      | ----
11 | https-download.opensuse.org-7c0c5e5f | SUSE:SLE-15-SP1:GA                                           | No      | ----      | ----
 7 | https-download.opensuse.org-31c9479b | home:kimi                                                    | No      | ----      | ----
 9 | https-download.opensuse.org-75a45d34 | server:database                                              | No      | ----      | ----
10 | https-download.opensuse.org-75f4f64c | home:bespokesynth:libs                                       | No      | ----      | ----
 6 | https-download.opensuse.org-2312c850 | SUSE:SLE-15-SP1:Update                                       | No      | ----      | ----
12 | https-download.opensuse.org-a01803b3 | network:im:signal                                            | No      | ----      | ----
13 | https-download.opensuse.org-b4a26c73 | home:hibby50                                                 | No      | ----      | ----
14 | https-download.opensuse.org-b695c6af | SUSE:SLE-15:Update                                           | No      | ----      | ----
15 | https-download.opensuse.org-b800ad06 | SUSE:SLE-15-SP3:GA                                           | No      | ----      | ----
16 | https-download.opensuse.org-e33eb299 | openSUSE:Backports:SLE-15-SP3                                | No      | ----      | ----
17 | https-download.opensuse.org-eb8758bc | openSUSE:Backports:SLE-15-SP3:Checks                         | No      | ----      | ----
18 | https-download.opensuse.org-fb44bba0 | SUSE:SLE-15-SP2:Update                                       | No      | ----      | ----
19 | openSUSE-Leap-${releasever}-1        | openSUSE-Leap-15.5-1                                         | No      | ----      | ----
20 | openSUSE:repo-non-oss                | repo-non-oss (15.5)                                          | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes
21 | openSUSE:repo-non-oss-debug          | repo-non-oss-debug (15.5)                                    | No      | ----      | ----
22 | openSUSE:repo-openh264               | repo-openh264 (15.5)                                         | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes
23 | openSUSE:repo-oss                    | repo-oss (15.5)                                              | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes
24 | openSUSE:repo-oss-debug              | repo-oss-debug (15.5)                                        | No      | ----      | ----
25 | openSUSE:repo-oss-source             | repo-oss-source (15.5)                                       | No      | ----      | ----
26 | openSUSE:update-backports            | update-backports (15.5)                                      | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes
27 | openSUSE:update-backports-debug      | update-backports-debug (15.5)                                | No      | ----      | ----
28 | openSUSE:update-non-oss              | update-non-oss (15.5)                                        | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes
29 | openSUSE:update-non-oss-debug        | update-non-oss-debug (15.5)                                  | No      | ----      | ----
30 | openSUSE:update-oss                  | update-oss (15.5)                                            | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes
31 | openSUSE:update-oss-debug            | update-oss-debug (15.5)                                      | No      | ----      | ----
32 | openSUSE:update-sle                  | update-sle (15.5)                                            | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes
33 | openSUSE:update-sle-debug            | update-sle-debug (15.5)                                      | No      | ----      | ----
34 | openSUSE_Leap_${releasever}          | Mozilla for Leap 15.5                                        | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes
35 | openSUSE_Leap_${releasever}_1        | Packman (full) for Leap 15.5                                 | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes
36 | repo-backports-update                | Update repository of openSUSE Backports                      | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes
37 | repo-sle-update                      | Update repository with updates from SUSE Linux Enterprise 15 | Yes     | (r ) Yes  | Yes

sudo zypper purge-kernels --dry-run:
Installierte Pakete werden gelesen...

Säuberung von veralteten Kerneln wird vorbereitet...
Konfiguration: latest,latest-1,running
Kernel Release läuft: 5.14.21-150500.55.68-default
Kernel arch läuft: x86_64

Paketabhängigkeiten werden aufgelöst...
Nothing to do.

Version data from Info Centre:
Operating System: openSUSE Leap 15.5
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.9
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.103.0
Qt Version: 5.15.8
Kernel Version: 5.14.21-150500.55.68-default (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-4702MQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
Memory: 11.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 4600
Manufacturer: Acer
Product Name: Aspire V3-772G
System Version: V1.15


The problem had become a little worse: I was up to 4 packages without update candidates!
I was able, at least for now, to get rid of this problem as follows with the YasT Software Updates function. I do not know if there is a downside to this solution! The steps I took were:

Start YasT from the start menu
From there, start the Software Updates function
Perform an update (Packages | All packages | Update if newer version available).

This reduced the problems back to just the two packages kernel-devel and kernel-default-devel in my question.


For these two packages

Search for the package

Click on it to show details

Click on the Versions tab in the lower half

Select the version (5.14.21-150500.53.2) for which a patch is listed


This should show a  rather than a , which appears in the previous image as I made it after the update.


Click Accept

Run the automatic Software Updates function () again

This reported the same old errors
It then checked again for available updates and said there were none




That seems to me to have solved the problem. I have not yet had another lot of patches since, but I shall report here if I have any problems when the next batch appears.

